# Why onDelete() doesn't work with my List view

Tags: listview, swiftui

I have following code in View of my macOS app

```
@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
@FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)]) private var processes: FetchedResults<Processes>

@ObservedObject var process = Process()
@State private var newProcess = false
@State private var selectedProcess: UUID?
@State private var processName = ""

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        VStack {
            Button("New process") {
                newProcess = true
            }.sheet(isPresented: $newProcess) {
                processSheet
            }
            List(selection: $selectedProcess) {
                ForEach(processes, id: \.id) { process in
                    Text(process.name!).tag(process.id!)
                }.onDelete() { index in
                    print("deleting \(index)")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I can't invoke any delete action via swipe-left gesture on List row. Is that because CoreData is involved? Thanks.

Comment: You haven't given us a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), which is a bit difficult with `Core Data`, but swipe to delete works just fine with `Core Data.` I would be a bit careful with your naming. You have an `@ObservedObject var process` and a different `process` as your `ForEach` closure argument. Swift could simply be confused. On another note, since your `Entity` is `Identifiable` so you can omit the `, id: \.id` in your `ForEach`.

Comment: it's not because of the `CoreData`, it's because of the `VStack`. Remove `VStack` and it will work.

Comment: Hi, removing VStack actually helped. Thanks.